# custom walker class for own menu?

Tags: menus, walker

i have designed a html template for own blog, in my theme my menu is this structure,

```
<ul class="right">
<li class="has-dropdown">
<a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="index.html">Home Page - Default</a></li>
<li><a href="index-type1.html">Home Page Type 1</a></li>
<li><a href="index-type2.html">Home Page Type 2</a></li>
<li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">TouchM Sliders</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="index.html">Slider Revolution</a></li>
<li><a href="index-flexi.html">Flexislider</a></li>
<li><a href="index-camera.html">Camera Slider</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="has-dropdown">
<a  href="#">Features</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
<li><a href="shortcodes.html">Shortcodes</a></li>
<li><a href="notfound.html">404 Not Found</a></li>
<li><a href="under-construction.html">Under Construction</a></li>
<li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Third Navigation Level</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">This is a simple example</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Of the Third Level</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>        
</li>

<li class="has-dropdown">
<a href="#">Blog</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="blog_sidebar_right.html">Blog Default</a></li>
<li><a href="blog_type1.html">Blog Type 1</a></li>
<li><a href="blog_type2.html">Blog Type 2</a></li>         
<li><a href="blog_sidebar_right.html">Sidebar Right</a></li>
<li><a href="blog_sidebar_left.html">Sidebar Left</a></li>
<li><a href="blog_inner.html">Single Post</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="has-dropdown">
<a href="#">Portfolio</a>
<ul class="dropdown">             
<li><a href="portfolio_default.html">Portfolio Default (4 Columns)</a></li>         
<li><a href="portfolio_type1.html" class="">Portfolio 2 Columns</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio_type2.html">Portfolio 3 Columns</a></li> 
<li><a href="portfolio_default.html">Portfolio 4 Columns</a></li>            
<li><a href="single-project.html">Single Project</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

but when i use wp nav menu to fecth menu , wordpress not correct create this, i google this problem and  then i undrestand to solve this problem muse use wp nav wlaker class, this time my question is which walker class compatible with this menu structure

Comment: Why are you trying to link to HTML files in a CMS?

Answer (score 1):

> this time my question is which walker class compatible with this menu
>   structure

Yes, you should be able to produce a walker to do that, but if you want markup completely different from what the menu API creates, why are you using the menu API? It is a waste of effort.

However, what I would suggest is that you work with WordPress instead of against it. The menu API can and does construct something very, very similar to what you have posted. Use the "Custom Links" to add arbitrary anchors, such as to your `.html` files. Take a look at that markup and make your CSS/Javascript/whatever work with it rather than trying to (essentially) force a non-WordPress menu into WordPress. You will be happier in the long term.